# Protractor Reloading Page Between It Statenents

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I completely understand if there isn't enough information, but here is what happens - the code below executes just fine. However, if I try to delete the 'cancelButton.click()' action and uncomment the second it statement, the page reloads and the cancelButton does not get clicked. This isn't the only place it's happening. It's almost like I have to put everything in one it statement, or the page reloads at random. I do NOT have any beforeEach statements.

```
it("Should click stuff ", function(){
    actionsButton.click();
    checkOutButton.click();
    cancelButton.click();
});

//it('Shouldn't fail like it is', function(){
//    cancelButton.click();
//});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any afterEach() or onPrepare()? There may be something in those blocks that is triggering your page reload issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Isn't onPrepare executed only once though? What's the difference between onPrepare and beforeAll anyway?

Comment: beforeAll is run in your spec file and specific to that spec file. where if you ran a suite of tests they could all have different beforeAll functions within the specs in the suite. But the onPrepare would be the same for all the spec files in the suite

Comment: Thanks Barret.  /comment length

Comment: Or if you are using **restartBrowserBetweenTests** tag in your conf.js file then you should setting it to false.

Comment: Checked that Girish, thanks. It's not it, but as long as we are making progress =) I will definitely update once we get it fixed. To be honest, it might be something with our npm set up. It runs when using webdriver-manager directly, but gets this error when using gulp to run the test. Though when I run directly, I have nothing in my conf file except the spec, whereas the gulp spec has hundreds of lines of code.